# Browser specific javascript inclusion

Tags: javascript

It seems like the browser conditionals:

```
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'cufon') . '/js/cufon-drupal.js',
 array('group' => JS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'gte IE 9', '!IE' => TRUE), 
'weight' => 999, 'preprocess' => FALSE));
```

included in template.php (or a module) are not working due to the fact `browsers` option is supported for `drupal_add_css()` but not for `drupal_add_js()`.

Can one state a not-hackish/patchy solution to exclude this file `cufon-drupal.js` on older browsers?

A solution like

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<script src='<?php drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'cufon') . '/js/cufon-drupal.js'); ?>'>
</script><![endif]-->
```

in html.tpl.php
is not working.

Comment: That second snippet doesn't need the drupal_add_js without it, would work

Answer (score -1):

Seems like there is a non-drupal solution:

```
if(jQuery.browser.version.substring(0, 2) != "8.") { alert("not ie8"); }
```

It is not very handy as I have to paste inside the brackets the content of cufon-drupal.js content.

Comment: Rather than relying on user agent strings (which are inherently unreliable) it might be better to do this using feature detection/IE conditional comments. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609282/detecting-ie8-reliably-using-javascript) for some ideas